# Find unknown area of the triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

Find the area of the triangle. As I understand, if we name the unkown area x, then x/120=300/200 or x/300=120/200 and from that x=180, but I have no idea how to prove that it's correct.

[image]

Comment: That is correct. You can prove this by using statements like: The area of a triangle $ABC$ is $\frac12 \overline{AB} \times \overline{AC} \times \sin A$.

Comment: Another way, use that the areas of two triangles with a common altitude are in the same proportion as their bases. It follows that the ratio of the segments on the "upwards" diagonal is $300 / 200\,$, and is also $x /120\,$.

Comment: "Missing quadrilateral"?? I think you're asking about a triangle, not a quadrilateral, and the triangle isn't missing, there's just a number that's missing. Stating problems clearly and correctly is half the battle in Mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way to more easily visualize this sort of solution is by adding to each triangle another, congruent triangle to make each a parallelogram, as in this very bad MS paint drawing:

[image]

From here I find it easier to see why

$$\frac{2?}{2\cdot 120} = \frac{2\cdot 300}{2\cdot 200},$$

even though it is true for the exact same reason (base times height).

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the above drawing, a few details:

Let

1)$ x$ be the common basis of the $2×?$ and $2×120 $ parallelograms.

2) $y$ be the common basis of the $2×300$ and $2×200$ parallelograms.

3) $H$ the height of the $2×?$ parallelogram.

4) $h$ the height of the $2×120$ parallelogram.

We have:

a) $yH=600;$

b)$yh= 400$;

c) $xh= 240. $

Find: $xH.$

Divide a) by b): $H/h = 600/(400).$

Multiply this by c):

$xH = \dfrac{240×600}{400} = 2×?.$